# Check array values and add resulted array as column to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I need to add array as column to Dataframe:

```
results['TEST'] = results.apply(lambda x: results_02, axis=1)
```

As result I'm getting Dataframe like this:

```
ID TEST
1  [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
2  [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
3  [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
4  [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
5  [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
6  [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

But I want to add condition to check if `results['ID'] in results_02`, add all values except existing to this row, and this I need to do for every row.

So result Dataframe need to be like this:

```
ID TEST
1  [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
2  [1,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
3  [1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
4  [1,2,3,5,6,7,8,9,10]
5  [1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9,10]
6  [1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9,10]
```

I thought that I can do it using:

```
results['TEST'] = results.apply(lambda x: results_02[:10] if x not in results_02[:10] else results_02.remove(x)[:10], axis=1)
```

But I'm getting error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

What is best and more optimized way to solve this problem?

EDIT_1:
DF

```
data = {'ID': [250274, 244473, 240274, 247178, 248667]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
results_02 = [250274, 244473, 240274, 247178, 248667]
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error without knowing `results` and `results_02`. Can you please provide them? Or, at least, part of them?

Comment: What do you mean by 'arrays as a column' . Did you turn them vertically or did you insert one array inside a cell

Comment: @ko3 yes, this question is incomplete

Comment: Array inside a cell. Like in question, 1st row: 1-1st column [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]-2nd column

Comment: Maybe this works results['TEST'] = [x for x in results['TEST'] if x not in results_02[:10] else results_02.remove(x)[:10]]

Comment: @ko3 Added df and data

Comment: @FeoJun, thanks, that makes it easier to support you. Does my solution solve your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = {'ID': [250274, 244473, 240274, 247178, 248667]}

results = pd.DataFrame(data)
result_02 = np.array([250274, 244473, 240274, 247178, 248667])

mask = results.values != result_02
results['TEST'] = [result_02[mask_row] for mask_row in mask]
results

----------------------------------------------
    ID       TEST
0   250274  [244473, 240274, 247178, 248667]
1   244473  [250274, 240274, 247178, 248667]
2   240274  [250274, 244473, 247178, 248667]
3   247178  [250274, 244473, 240274, 248667]
4   248667  [250274, 244473, 240274, 247178]
----------------------------------------------
```

If your data frame contains several columns and you are interested only in the `ID` column, then you have to specify your mask by reshaping you ID array.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = {'ID': [250274, 244473, 240274, 247178, 248667], 'some_col': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']}

results = pd.DataFrame(data)
result_02 = np.array([250274, 244473, 240274, 247178, 248667])

mask = results.ID.values.reshape(-1, 1) != result_02
results['TEST'] = [result_02[mask_row] for mask_row in mask]
```

##### EDIT

I am not quit sure what you mean by your comment. I suppose you want something like that?

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'ID1': [250274, 244473, 240274, 247178, 248667],
    'ID2': [244473, 240274, 247178, 248667, 250274],
}



results = pd.DataFrame(data)
result_02 = np.array([250274, 244473, 240274, 247178, 248667])

results['TEST'] = [result_02[~np.in1d(result_02, row)] for row in results.values]

------------------------------------------------
    ID1     ID2     TEST
0   250274  244473  [240274, 247178, 248667]
1   244473  240274  [250274, 247178, 248667]
2   240274  247178  [250274, 244473, 248667]
3   247178  248667  [250274, 244473, 240274]
4   248667  250274  [244473, 240274, 247178]
------------------------------------------------
```

If not, please make your comment more precise.

Comment: But what if ehere will be several columns, how to make `mask = results['ID'].values != result_02` this work properly?

Comment: @FeoJun, I edited my answer. Is that what you was looking for? Also, please be more precise with your question next time, you was referring to one column in your question.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't precise enough in the comment. I wanted to consider the case when we have multiple columns and we can't use `mask = result.values != result_02`, since the wrong result will be selected there. And if you use `task = results['ID'].values != result_02`, where we explicitly specify `'ID'`, then there will also be an incorrect mask. And then what to do in this case? For example df with columns `['ID','DATE','ADDRESS']` where we need to filter `'TEST'` only on `'ID'` column. Thank you for more complex example, it's also very useful

Comment: For this case, if your data frame contains more than one columns but you are only interested in the `ID` column, you have to reshape your array in order to create the true mask, like that: `mask = results['ID'].values.reshape(-1, 1) != result_02`. See my answer. Hope that helps
`

Answer (score 0):

I used that solution:

```
results['RESULTS'] = results['ID'].apply(lambda x: [i for i in result_02 if x!=i])
```